# org.gradle.api.artifacts.ResolveException: Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:_debugCompile'

Tags: admob, google-play-services

Im trying to integrate an Ad banner on my android app, but when i run it i get the following error message :

```
Could not find com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:15.0.1.
Searched in the following locations:
file:/C:/Program Files/Android/Android 
Studio/gradle/m2repository/com/google/android/gms/play-services-        
ads/15.0.1/play-services-ads-15.0.1.pom
file:/C:/Program Files/Android/Android             
Studio/gradle/m2repository/com/google/android/gms/play-services- 
ads/15.0.1/play-services-ads-15.0.1.jar
https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/android/gms/play-services- 
ads/15.0.1/play-services-ads-15.0.1.pom
https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/android/gms/play-services-    
ads/15.0.1/play-services-ads-15.0.1.jar
file:/C:/Users/Mottia.....
```

Following my Build.gradle file :

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.onlines.mushafkareem"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 19
    versionName "1.1.0"
    multiDexEnabled true
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 
'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:15.0.0'
}
```

I believe its an error that has something to do with th version of play services of google, 
can someone please help me to fix that ?
If you need anything else let me know, Thanks in advance.